# Зависает страница из-за регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Такая проблема, стандартная валидация email поля пропускает такие форматы мыла как `..example@some.com`, `examp..le@some.com`.

решил попробовать написать свою регулярку, в них я не силён, тема новая для меня.

> ```
> ^([-_a-z0-9].?[-_a-z0-9]?)+[-_a-z0-9]{1}@(?:[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+.)+[a-z]{2,6}$
> ```

Регулярка выше отрабатывает, но при большом количестве символов, зависает страница. Как можно её оптимизировать или может кто-то знает получше вариант.

Самое главное требование, чтобы в начале не было точек и не было две точки подряд.

Comment: Не нужно проверять email.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что точка неправильно написана. Дважды.

PS: Не надо проверять email!

Comment: а почему не нужно проверять?

Comment: потому что найдётся пользователь с почтой, которая под проверяемые правила не подходит и он будет недоволен. почту надо проверять отправкой на неё письма.

Comment: Наверное, вначале можно проверять такой регуляркой `.+?@.+`, а потом слать письма

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, можно, но судя по вопросу, уже есть `<input type=email>`.